# Building a toggle with ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't figure out why this code doesn't work as a toggle. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
  <div ng-switch="!!myvar">
    <a ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="myvar = true" style="cursor:pointer">
      false
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default ng-click="myvar = false" style="cursor:pointer">
      true
    </a>
  </div>
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.0-rc.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive `ng-switch` creates a new scope, so you need to use `$parent` to update the `myvar` in the parent scope.

```
<a ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="$parent.myvar = true" style="cursor:pointer">
<a ng-switch-default ng-click="$parent.myvar = false" style="cursor:pointer">
```